# SQL Condition Statement in Select By Attributes query

Tags: arcgis-desktop, sql, select-by-attribute, arcgis-10.5

[image]I am attempting to execute a Select query in Select By Attributes where the return record set I'm looking for includes all records where the String value is greater than 7 characters long.

For ex., I have records in my table where the value in the "LeftCityCo" field is 2395187, and other records where the value in the "LeftCityCo" field is 2395934ANO. I'm seeking to obtain a Selection that includes all records with values in this field greater than 7 characters long.

I've tried using the Left function and attempted the following query but returned an error:

Select * From Streets Where
"LeftCityCo" = Left( "LeftCityCo", 7 )[image]

Comment: `WHERE Length("LeftCityCo") > 7`

Comment: WHERE Length("LeftCityCo") > 7 will NOT work in ArcGIS Select by Attributes

Comment: I tried the Where clause suggested and correct, it did not work. Thank you all for your suggestions. Would anyone have any further ideas on how to obtain this Selection set in ArcGIS?

Comment: oops, sorry... try `CHAR_LENGTH("LeftCityCo") > 7`

Answer (score 1):

I did not have my code syntactically correct for my Select By Attributes query box. Because I was using this ui, I needed to change my expression to suit file types such as shapefile, File GDB and so on. I was attempting to use SQL syntax and that was incorrect.

Below is the code expression that returned the result I was expecting:

CHAR_LENGTH( "LeftCityCo" ) > 7

Answer (score 0):

Open the Select by Attributes window for the appropriate table and use the following expression

```
len("LeftCityCo") > 7
```

Quotes around the fieldname were not required with my data set but yours may be
[image]

Comment: I still get "An invalid SQL statement was used." when attempting that expression.

Comment: Can you show me exactly (picture) of the attribute table with that field showing

Comment: How do I post a screen capture?

Comment: Edit your question to include the image. You can upload directly from your pc

Comment: Image added to Question.

Comment: You did not copy my code snippet exactly. Copy and paste it exactly

Comment: Updated image added to Question.

Comment: Michael, delete all text in the query box and copy and paste the sql expression i provided you with. Do not add anything else

Comment: Sorry, I don't believe I understand - I have your query in my text box exactly as you provided it. I cannot take out the "SELECT * FROM Streets_Staging_20171206 WHERE:" portion.

Comment: In your image you posted. Remove the “leftcityco” = portion

Comment: Oh, no sorry - I have an updated image posted to the Question. That should have the screen capture showing the updated sql expression without the "LeftCityCo =" portion.

Comment: I updated my SQL expression in the answer to include qutoes around the field name. My dataset did not require it but yours may